# Javafx: How to use a driver file for a source file to show shape created

Tags: java, javafx, shapes, scene, stage

I'm trying to understand the driver file I've been given for a certain problem I'm working on. I just started learning javafx and I'm try to create a shape inside the driver file, but the extra code of initializing, mouse events, etc. are in the source file. I created a function that returns the initialized X for the rectangle and a system.out.println in my driver file so I know they are connected. However whenever I run my driver file, I get a blank screen without the shape on it. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with the scene/root/stage showing.

Heres my Code:

Multishape.java:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Multishape extends Group {
//Declaring variables here gives them greater scope

private Rectangle rectangle;
private Circle circle;
Group root = new Group();

public Multishape (double x, double y, double len){
  rectangle = new Rectangle(len, len, Color.BLUE);
  rectangle.setX(x);
  rectangle.setY(y);
  circle = new Circle(len, Color.RED);    

}

//@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    //rectangle.setOnMouseClicked(handleMouseClick);//Set mouse click handler
    //circle.setOnMouseClicked(handleMouseClick);//Set mouse click handler

    root.getChildren().add(rectangle);//Set initial shape.

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}


double getLen(){
  return (rectangle.getX());
}

}
```

MultishapeDriver.java:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

public class MultishapeDriver extends Application
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }

  public void start(Stage stage)
  {
    stage.setTitle("Multishape lab");
    Group root = new Group();
    Multishape shape = new Multishape(320, 240, 40);
    root.getChildren().add(shape);
//stage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, shape.getKeyHandler());

System.out.println(shape.getLen());
stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 640, 480));
stage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: You never add any children to `Multishape`. This way the object has no effect on the rendered result. I'd expect `this.getChildren().add(rectangle);` at the end of the constructor. The `root` field and the `start` method should be removed from the `Multishape` class, if I understand the intention behind this class correctly. BTW: not sure why you're using the terminology *"driver"* here. I'd expect a driver to be something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

Your Multishape is a container of type Group.
But in its constructor, you only create 2 objects, you never adde them to your multishape.
Sou you'll need to add them with `getChildren().add(rectangele)`, etc to your multishape.

Your Multishape constructor would then look like this:

```
public Multishape (double x, double y, double len){
  rectangle = new Rectangle(len, len, Color.BLUE);
  rectangle.setX(x);
  rectangle.setY(y);
  circle = new Circle(len, Color.RED);    
  getChildren().add(rectangle);
  getChildren().add(circle);
}
```